# Can't scale nurbs circle along normals

Tags: transforms, normals

I'm trying to scale a NURBs path along it's normals with <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd>, but it just wont go.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K4X7.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your file seems to be behaving as expected, so this looks like a misunderstanding about what to expect?

The <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> shortcut is to an Edit Mode operation. On a curve, it adjusts the Radius of a its control-points, which, in turn, will alter the transverse scale of any profile swept along it...

[image]

It sounds as if your key-map may be covered / absent. Call up Edit > Preferences > Keymap.

This one's quite tricky to search for; it's a Mode under Curve Transform. I found the best search was 'Transform', and then a scroll down to the 'Curve' section, where you can expand this:

[image]

Select the 'Shrink / Fatten' Mode, have a look, and see whether the shortcut is set to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: Hi Robin - thanks for the response and help. What you showed in the screenshot is exactly what I'm trying to do, albeit unsuccessfully. For some reason, I just can't scale it like you do. Is there some kind of setting I tripped that prevents it from scaling?   https://imgur.com/a/ftPZMEX

Comment: @Frank Maybe you've covered the keymap? Can you still 'Set Curve Radius' in the Edit > Right-Click menu, or in the N Panel > Item > Transform?

Comment: pardon my ignorance but not sure what is meant with keymap but yes, I can still change the radius in the tool options which has the same effect as alt-s. Why Alt-s is not working however still remains a mystery.....

Comment: @Frank   no need to apologize .. we're all learning, here... since it's a possible cause, when I get a chance, I'll expand this answer to show checking / editing your key-map (which assigns keyboard shortcuts to operations, under Edit > Preferences > Keymap)  But you may be ahead of me, there? I'm quite busy for a bit.

Comment: @Frank edited, maybe this will fix.